# Producer/Consumer with shared memory and processes

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

i can't understand what it's wrong with this code. I have a shared variable(portions) allocated with shared memory. When there are zero portions, producer(chef) fills the pot, consumer(savage) consumes portions for NROUNDS. I don't know why the variable portions isn't decremented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

sem_t mutex,empty,full;
int shmid;
int *portions;

void clear()  //destroy semaphores and shared memory
{
   sem_destroy(&mutex);
   sem_destroy(&empty);
   sem_destroy(&full);
   if (shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0) == -1) perror("shmctl");
}

void producer(int num, int m)   //chef that produces portions
{
  int i, j;

   while(1) {  

    sem_wait(&mutex); //join critical region
    sem_wait(&empty);
    *portion=m; 
    printf("Chef fills the pot\n");
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sem_post(&full);
   }      
}

void consumer(int num, int rounds, int m)   //savage that consumes portions
{

       int i, diff, n, j;

        for(i=0;i<rounds;i++) { 
           sleep(3);
           sem_wait(&mutex);
           if((*portion)==0) {
              sem_post(&empty);
              sem_wait(&full); 
            }        
         n=rand() % m;
         diff=(*portion)-n;  //consumes portions
         printf("Savage[%d] has eaten %d portions\n", num, diff);
         printf("Portions number in pot: %d\n", *portion);
         sem_post(&mutex);

     }  

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i;
int N, M, NROUNDS, pid;


if (argc != 4) 
{
    fprintf(stderr,"insert N savages, M portions and NROUNDS\n");
    exit(1);
}

N=atoi(argv[1]);
M=atoi(argv[2]);
NROUNDS=atoi(argv[3]);

// initialize semaphores and shared memory

sem_init(&mutex,1,1);

sem_init(&empty,1,M);

sem_init(&full,1,0);

shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0600);
  if (shmid == -1) perror("Creation shared memory");
  portions = (int *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
  if (portions == (void *)-1) perror("Attach shared memory");
  *portions=M; //initialize shared variable(M is max portions in pot)

/* initialize producer and consumers (1 Producer and N Consumers) */



    if (fork()==0)
        { producer(i, M); exit(0);} //producer


   for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if (fork()==0)
            { consumer(i, NROUNDS, M); exit(0);} //consumers
      }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
    pid=wait(NULL);
    printf("Terminated process %d\n", pid); //wait terminating processes
  }    

  clear();

}
```

Output is like this:

```
./a.out 3 20 3

Chef fills the pot
Chef fills the pot
Chef fills the pot
Chef fills the pot
Chef fills the pot
Chef fills the pot
Chef fills the pot
Savage[2] has eaten 17 portions
Savage[1] has eaten 17 portions
Savage[0] has eaten 17 portions
Portions number in pot: 20
Portions number in pot: 20
Portions number in pot: 20
Savage[1] has eaten 14 portions
Savage[0] has eaten 14 portions
Savage[2] has eaten 14 portions
Portions number in pot: 20
Portions number in pot: 20
Portions number in pot: 20
Savage[2] has eaten 3 portions
Savage[0] has eaten 3 portions
Savage[1] has eaten 3 portions
Portions number in pot: 20
Portions number in pot: 20
Terminated process 4432
Portions number in pot: 20
Terminated process 4431
Terminated process 4433
```

Comment: "*I don't know why the variable portions isn't decremented.*" because there is no code doing so?

Comment: This: diff=(*portion)-n;

Comment: Never use the `sem_` functions without checking for their return value. They may be interrupted by signals such as IO. Code that you write like this will show weird spurious behavior that is very difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check the whole code, but it looks as if here

```
           n=rand() % m;
```

the code calculates the portions eaten.

Then calculates the remaining portions here

```
           diff=(*portion)-n;
```

and *wrongly* prints them as those eaten here

```
           printf("Savage[%d] has eaten %d portions\n", num, diff);
```

The code does not remove them from the pot (`m`).

To fix this do

```
           n=rand() % m; // get portions eaten in to n
           diff=(*portion)-n;  // get the remaining portions
           printf("Savage[%d] has eaten %d portions\n", num, n); // log
           (*portion) = diff; // or just  (*portion) -= n; and drop diff at all.
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know why, starting the program, there's a loop of the producer and when the variable portion is <=0, producer doesn't fills the pot?

Comment: I thought twice what the idea behind the code you show could be and significantly adjusted my answer.

Comment: It's there(i adjusted it)     if((*portion)<=0) {
                                          sem_post(&empty);
                                          sem_wait(&full);